# Cordova automated build of an existing web project

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, webpack

I'm looking for a way to build a cordova app completely automatically, based on a existing web project. All I have found so far is to create a new cordova project and drag and drop my existing application in the www folder. The thing is, I don't want to do this step.

Therefore, I'm looking for one of these two possible solutions.

**1. Privately hosted phonegap build alternative**

Is there an open source project similar to phonegap build? One that I can host on my private servers. All I have to do in this case is zipping my project, upload it to the server and get the built application back.

What I have found is cordova-build (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-build), but it seams quite out-dated and not well maintained.

**2. Create a local build process**

For the building process I'm using webpack. So what I would like to do is setting up a build process where I can just say

```
npm mobileBuild -- --platform="ios"
```

and it builds a new cordova project with my web application included. Later I would just have to run the cordova cli commands to build the application.

Do you have any idea how to accomplish one of these two approaches?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The existing web project must consider cordova related HTML like

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

But it will be missing on the already developed project... even the HTML/CSS will have to be different for every case.
I don't really see this as a way to follow, not automatically.